# configuración de ssl de tomcat 9

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Instale los certificados de godaddy en el servidor con estos comandos:

> keytool -import -alias root -keystore C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\mercadorefacciones_com_mx.jks
>   -trustcacerts -file D:\certificates\gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
>
> keytool -import -alias intermed -keystore C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\mercadorefacciones_com_mx.jks
>   -trustcacerts -file D:\certificates\gdig2.crt.pem
>
> keytool -import -alias tomcat -keystore C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\mercadorefacciones_com_mx.jks
>   -trustcacerts -file D:\certificates\1c1f16606d7eadb7.crt

y en el server.xml puse esta configuracion:

```
<Connector port="8443"
           protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
maxThreads="200"
         scheme="https" secure="true" SSLEnabled="true" >
    <SSLHostConfig>
        <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin\mercadorefacciones_com_mx.jks"
                     certificateKeystorePassword="123456"
                     certificateKeyAlias="server"
                     type="RSA" />
    </SSLHostConfig>
</Connector>
```

Pero al intentar cargar https://localhost:8443 me da el error de timeout.

Y en el log he visto el siguiente error: **"Alias name [server] does not identify a key entry"**

Comment: Normalmente, un problema con la configuración SSL no da un *timeout* sino errores de *SSL Handshake* o errores 500. ¿Estás seguro de que no hay otro problema? Además, no sé si es un error de transcripción o no, el *keystore* que defines con el *keytool* no tiene la misma ruta que el de tu configuración. En todo caso, sería útil que miraras el log del tomcat al arrancar,  no sea que el problema de configuración se detecte allí y simplemente no levante el puerto 8443

Comment: Gracias sJuan76, mire el log y me arroja esto Alias name [server] does not identify a key entry y en el alias de ultimo crt que subi si es "server"

Comment: Los tres alias que defines en tu *keystore* son *root*, *interned* y *tomcat*. Si ése es el keystore que usas, `certificateKeyAlias` debería ser uno de esos.

Comment: Intente con los 3 marca el mismo error

Comment: Como comenté antes, comprueba que estés usando el *keystore* que defines en tus comandos... la ruta al *keystore* no coincide.

Comment: Si, ya tengo la ruta igual.

Comment: Lo logre, borre todos los alias y empeze otra vez solo que ahora debo de forzar a que el usuario se valla al https. Saludos.